# Angular2 - Role based AuthGuard

Tags: angular, rxjs

My goal is to implement an AuthGuard that checks if a user has access to a specific route based on their role and the requested route and allow them to proceed if they have the right role for the route, or redirect them elsewhere if they do not.

The AuthGuard calls my AuthorizationService which returns an Observable(UserRole).  I am having difficulty evaluating the user's observable and returning a value to canActivate. It is certainly related to my inexperience with RxJS Observables but I cannot seem to get past this one.

I have  **auth.guard.service.ts**

```
 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {        

        let url: string = state.url;

        var currentUser$ = this.authService.getCurrentUser();

        currentUser$.subscribe((currentUser: MyUser) => {    

            if (currentUser.isInternalUser && url === '/internal') {
                console.debug("Internal User! Yes");
                this.router.navigate(['/internal']);
                return true;
            } else if (currentUser.isExternalUser && url === '/dashboard') {
                console.debug("External User! Yes");                    
                this.router.navigate(['/external']);
                return true;
            } else {
                console.debug("Access Denied...");
                this.router.navigate(['/pagenotfound']);
                return false;
            }
        });

       //return Observable.of(false);  // I need to return something, but this is not what I want to return!!

    }
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
 getCurrentUser() : Observable<MyUser> {

        let currentUser$: Observable<MyUser>;

        currentUser$ = this.http.get(this.location.prepareExternalUrl('api/v1/userprofile/')) 
            .cache()       
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);

        console.log("AuthService#getCurrentUser being called.");

        return currentUser$;
    }
```

How can I evaluate my currentUser and have *canActivate* return a boolean observable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the `Observable` before you subscribe to it. Subscribing is a terminal operation that informs the Observable that it is now connected and that it can begin pushing events to the subscribers (represented by the handlers you pass to the subscribe function).

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean> {
   const url: string = state.url;
   return this.authService.getCurrentUser()
     .flatMap(({isInternalUser, isExternalUser}: MyUser) => {
       if (isInternalUser && url === '/internal') {
         return Observable.fromPromise(this.router.navigate(['/internal']))
           .mapTo(true);
       } else if (isExternalUser && url === '/dashboard') {
         return Observable.fromPromise(this.router.navigate(['/external']))
           .mapTo(true);
       } else {
         return Observable.fromPromise(this.router.navigate(['/pagenotfound']))
           .mapTo(false);
       }
     });        
}
```

The above is a naive refactoring of the code that you supplied. I am afraid I don't know enough about Angular2 to tell you if that is actually how you should be implementing an Auth Guard (though I will say it does seem a little odd to be redirecting in what is ostensibly just a check of *whether* that page is accessible).

Also on a side note, `cache` is being removed from the final release of RxJS 5 so you may want to avoid using it if you plan to upgrade.

Comment: I landed on this:
 var currentUser$ = this.authService.getCurrentUser();
        
        return currentUser$.map(x => {
            if (x.isExternalUser && url === '/dashboard') {
                return true;
            } else if (x.isInternalUser && url === '/internal') {
                return true;
            } else {
                this.router.navigate(['/pagenotfound']);
                return false;
            }
        });

Comment: Fair enough, though I would point out that you will lose the result of that redirect since you aren't waiting for it to return when you navigate to the page not found url.

Comment: @PaulDaniels Makes sense - that explains why you used `Observable.fromPromise`.  I'll incorporate that into my code.  I'm very new to RxJs and I'm still trying to get a handle on it.

Comment: @paulpdaniels what is state.url here?

Comment: @Euridice01 not sure, it was in the OP's example, I assume since it comes from the `RouterStateSnapshot` that it is the current `url`